# No accounts with iTunes Connect access have been found for the team

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

In Xcode, when I try to `Product > Archive > Validate App` I get the error:

> No accounts with iTunes Connect access have been found for the team "TEAM_NAME". iTunes Connect access is required for App Store distribution.

and/or

> No accounts with App Store Connect access have been found for the team "TEAM_NAME". App Store Connect access is required for App Store Connect distribution.

and/or

> Unable to authenticate with App Store Connect

[image: Xcode error screenshot]

How can I fix this issue and validate my app?

Comment: I am having the same issue as of today.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. iTunes Connect has been a mess for the last month or so. I was able to get it uploaded by using the Application Loader. Funny thing; is that I have 3 apps that I'm uploading simultaneously. The first app went up, no problem. The second app puked this way. I cleaned rebuilt, and tried again. That worked. The third one refused to upload, no matter what. I exported, then used Application Loader, and that worked.

Comment: Deleting `DerivedData` and doing a clean build fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Restart Xcode solved my issue. This isn't 1st time, and will not be last time.What a worst software quality...... I can't even count how many times I have to restart Xcode, restart OSX, or get into terminal to run some creepy command to get Xcode work as it should be ......

Comment: Check space on disk in my case there was not space so i clean some data and fixed the issue

Answer (score 732, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

- Quit Xcode completely and re-open it to resolve the problem.

**Solution 2:**

- Please verify if it's `App Store distribution profile` or not.
- If yes then try to login to Xcode with your apple Id which has access
  to `iTunes Connect` or `App Store Connect`.
- While validating the archive file please choose the same profile. It
  should work fine.

Comment: Hi Aditya, I am using XCode 9.3 and facing this issue continuously...tried clearning drived data, deleting folders..creating another apple id and assigned as admin....restart machine...restart XCode all time....deleting all certificate from key chain... but still I am facing this issue... please help me out if you can...

Comment: @AnuragDixit did you solve the problem? How ?,  I have the same issue  , thanks

Comment: Restart for me fixed as well. Par for the course for Xcode.

Comment: A restart did help for me, try this first! If that does not help look for other issues...

Comment: I had to logout and login again. Restarting XCode was not enough.

Comment: Restart Xcode works for me...! Xcode version: 10.2.1

Comment: Another issue is firewall. Had this today, I am able to access appstoreconnect via https but when uploading it fails stating the issue above

Comment: had many projects with different dev accounts actions:  close, open only the one i wanted to upload and worked correctly.

Comment: strong case for macs with ECC i suppose. if you can afford the pittance that is

Comment: The edit of 2018 December seems 'stole' the second answer below...

Comment: The issue is still present with Xcode 12.3

Answer (score 360):

When this happens to me, closing Xcode completely and re-opening it solves the problem.

Comment: Lol, it works for me too. I think this should be marked as a right answer.

Comment: Late 2019 and this is still happening, and being fixed by this answer.

Comment: had to add a log-out and log-in to the equation after that it worked...

Comment: XCode 11.5, June 2020. Still going strong.

Comment: It worked for me too i am using Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33).
why this answer isn't accepted?

Comment: it's August 2022, and this method helped...

Answer (score 38):

Ran into this problem just now. Complete shutdown and restart of Xcode did the trick for me.

Comment: This solution works for me when it happens. Annoying odd bug.

Comment: Agree, just had it today

Answer (score 26):

Just restart Xcode and it will work :)

Definitely it will work in Xcode 9 alternate you can try with Application Loader.

Answer (score 16):

### Swift 5, iOS 13

Just restart Xcode, everything works

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your network firewall doesn`t block iTunes connect domain. You might experience with the same message if it is blocked.

For me, iTunes & AppStore access is blocked firewall network level. I restart Xcode and mac, it worked like charm.

Comment: This was my issue. Once it was unblocked from network firewall it started working. Upvoting this answer as the error message on Xcode is misleading and I wasted a lot of time reaching the root cause.

Answer (score 6):

Restart Xcode or Restart your mac, In my case I just restart Xcode

Comment: restarting xcode only did not work, when restarted the mac, worked for me

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE XCODE 10**

**September 2019**

If closing Xcode doesn't work, **try logging out and logging in with the Apple Developer Account**, *which may not be the same as the iCloud account* in many cases.

These two steps would solve 95% of these error cases.

Comment: This is what did it for me

Answer (score 6):

Another solution that works for me is to **disable** `Automatically manage signing` and then restart the Xcode.

Then I **enable** again the `Automatically manage signing` to upload the application.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Go to: **Xcode** > **Preferences**...

1. Remove your account
2. Add your apple ID again

   [image: Accounts]

Comment: When I went here - wasn't logged in suddenly - just logged in and worked.

Comment: Yes, it's work for me. Restart xcode dont help me in this problem

Answer (score 4):

For the XCode 12 and above.
Closing the Xcode and reopen solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just restart not only Xcode, but also the OS.
Didn't believe it, but really, just restart.

Answer (score 2):

I tried these three solutions and things were back to normal

**Solution 1:**

Completely close Xcode and Safari.

**Solution 2:**

Logout and login your apple developer account in Xcode preferences

**Solution 3:**

Go to your Keychain and deleting the old expired certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure apple store domain can be accessed, in my case it was blocked by network admin, i found this after struggling for 2 days in this

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Turned out that App Store was blocked by IT (arrrggggg!!!). Try a different network or ask IT to unblock then should work but first check that you can access App Store

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers didn't work for me, including restarting, quitting Xcode and refreshing profiles.

Disconnected from company VPN and instantly started working.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a lot of solutions to this problem and none of the above worked for me. What did work for me was going into `Keychain` and deleting some old expired certificates.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE XCODE 11**

If the restarting of Xcode doesn't work, then try logout and login again in with the Apple Developer Account in the xcode.

Process:

**Xcode > Preferences**

Remove your account by clicking on - sign button

Add your apple ID again by clicking on the plus (+) sign button

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem just now.
Complete shutdown and restart of Xcode did **NOT** do the trick for me at first!
I also had to close the Safari browser which was running in the background.

After both Xcode and Safari was completely closed.
I open Safari and navigated to the "App store connect" page -> login.
Then I opened Xcode -> run Archive - Validate.  and it worked :)

**Explanation of problem maybe.**
I have changed WiFi connections, from office to home office with both Xcode and the Safari browser open, and they must then have gotten confused of the wifi change, and remembered old connection data.

Comment: I can confirm that changing the WiFi connections was the reason for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today .I had logged in with the apple id to an iOS device and linked with iCloud that was creating issue to me  so once i removed the account from the device it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when I have the same Apple Id added to the accounts of Xcode on two devices. After removing the account from one device, the other one can upload to App Store fine. I did restart Xcode after removing, not sure if that's necessary. Maybe it's more like a session expires or connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been solved, but none of the listed solutions worked for me and in case someone else is also experiencing this issue- it could be due to not enabling Two-Factor Authentication.

I was having no problems uploading builds to the App Store and within the span of 1 hour got this same issue. Once I followed [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/authentication/) and enabled Two-Factor Authentication for both my organization's Team Agent as well as my own developer account, I restarted XCode and was able to successfully upload builds again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. I tried rebooting etc. and nothing worked. I tried again several hours later and managed to submit successfully. I can only assume the service was down.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Application Loader, if all the above fails.

Step 1:- Create a .ipa file for app store distribution.

Step 2:- Login to Application loader with your apple developer account for   which you are uploading your app.

Step 3:- Choose .ipa file from application loader, read the instruction asked and follow the steps.

I got the same issue, after spending lots of time and doing each and every thing but no solution work for me, at the last I just upload me .ipa file in Application Loader. And it work.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 10. Aug. 2019**

Press the Manage Account then see a reminder said my account is expired.
Logging in again fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

While developing using XCode, I found many errors only solved with restarting XCode and Macbook. Just restart the Macbook and it will be gone. Anything else except restarting is not worth of time. I have tried many things to solve this error. I tried to log in again and again with AppStore but only restarting MacBook worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If closing Xcode or restarting the Mac didn't help, try deleting Derived Data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all apple accounts
close xcode
restart mac
add apple account
it will work

Answer (score 0):

make sure that project navigator under both pods and runner, and signing & capabilities tab the team is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting DerivedData and restarting XCode solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sign-in Session is Expired,

Please login to developer account again in

Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts

Answer (score -1):

#### It founds it, but doe's not let you access it!

Recently Apple applied the US sanctions to some countries in a more restricted way and resulted in this issue. Also, you can see this issue if you head to some of Apple's online resources like the [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com) and see this instead:

[image]

> The page you’re looking for can’t be found.

This error is **NOT** a `404` error, as you can see in the console! It's a `403` and can be solved by using a good quality **VPN**

<sub>Some VPN's are already detected by major companies like Google and Apple and will not work for this issue</sub>

I hope it helps everyone, and I hope Apple discontinue this racist behavior