# No accounts with App Store Connect access have been found for the team

Tags: xcode

I got this error when submitting an iOS app to the App Store. Product → Archive, clicking "Distribute App" in the Organizer in Xcode 10.

[image]

> No accounts with App Store Connect access have been found for the team "[My Team Name]". App Store Connect access is required for App Store distribution.

I've logged into App Store Connect as the correct user account and verified that I have administrative access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No accounts with iTunes Connect access have been found for the team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592840/no-accounts-with-itunes-connect-access-have-been-found-for-the-team)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

App Store Connect used to be called "iTunes Connect," and so this question was answered by [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49735868/54829).

> When this happens to me, closing Xcode completely and re-opening it solves the problem.

Restarting Xcode fixed the problem for me, too.

Hopefully now that I've posted this question, someone can Google for "App Store Connect" and find the right answer.

Comment: It's Xcode 10.1 right now, but Apple cannot fix bugs to make our life a bit easier.

Comment: Same issue on XCode 11.0. Fortunately, this "solution" still works, thanks

Comment: Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146) still has the same "feature". The solution still works...

Comment: Worked for me too. Strange bug.

Comment: Xcode Version 11.7. This solution worked for me too

Comment: Xcode Version 12.1. Same issue, same solution.

Comment: Xcode Version 12.4. Issue still remains, solution still works.

Comment: xcode 12.5. Issue remains, your solution still works, Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure it'll work in xcode 13 and 14 too :^)

Comment: Thanks mate! you helped me solving my problem. all it need was a restart.

Comment: Still an issue in xcode 13.2 and restart xcode still works

Answer (score 7):

Awesome. Quick restart and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have an account in App Store Connect the provided solution (i.e. closing and re-opening Xcode) will not work.

Kindly see the following section from official Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/).

The person who enrolled in the Apple Developer Program is the main account holder and has the Legal role in App Store Connect, which includes binding authority for contracts, full access to App Store Connect, and more.

The Legal user can provide access to additional team members by setting up accounts for them in App Store Connect. Please note that adding members to a development team on the Apple Developer website will not automatically create accounts for those members in App Store Connect.

Add users by entering their names and email addresses in Users and Access. You can limit each user’s access level for App Store Connect and specific apps. If a user needs full access to App Store Connect, you can assign them the Admin role.

Comment: I don’t think this is the answer. I’m literally the account owner and I can’t get in either. Even though everything is paid up and signed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, we had a lot of expired **iOS distribution certificates**. Yes, not Mac ones, iOS ones. Deleting those solved the problem `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

Quitting the XCode completely and restarting it still gets the issue fixed. But check if your certificates are still valid if this problem persists.