# No accounts with App Store Connect access have been found for the team Xcode 11.7

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I added my .p12 file to keychain and my signing certificate selected in Xcode, when I try to Product > Archive > Distribute App I get the error:

[image]

I tried everything in this link [No accounts with iTunes Connect access have been found for the team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592840/no-accounts-with-itunes-connect-access-have-been-found-for-the-team).

But my error still same.

How can i fix this error

Answer (score 1):

To be able to upload an app to App Store Connect you will need to add your App Store Connect account to Xcode. Adding the certificates only allows you to build and sign the app, but not to upload it to App Store Connect.

In Xcode go to Preferences > Accounts > Add the account you want to upload the app to.