# How can I fix this "No accounts with appstore connect access have been found for the team 'Apple inc.' "?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

Whenever I try to upload my app to the appstore I get this error.

```
No accounts with appstore connect access have been found for the team "Apple inc." 
App Store connect access is required for App Store Connect Distribution
```

It also says for the team "Apple inc." instead of my own name/app name. I'm using carthage with two frameworks called SDWebImage and SwiftyJSON. Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When i face with this issue, closing Xcode completely and re-opening solves the issue.
Other than that maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49593025/14761695